# Cannot find module 'express'; Cannot find name 'process'; and so on

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am very new to Visual Studio Code, having made a sideways move from Visual Studio 2015.

I am writing my first nodejs/Angular 2 fiasco in VSC using webpack. The sample application provided by express-generator worked a treat, but now I am moving on to writing my own code, mainly in TypeScript.

I have this code in app.ts:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as path from 'path';

var controllers = require('./controllers');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'vash');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// map the routes
controllers.init(app);

// development only
if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// set up server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Express server listening on port ${app.get('port') }`);
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
path = require('path');

var app = __dirname;

module.exports = {
    context: app,
    entry: {
        app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './app.ts']
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: app,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts"
    ]
}
```

I have a number of issues raised by VSC. On the first line of my .ts, "Cannot find module 'express'." Now I have run "npm intall express -g" and even "npm install express" so I don't know why it's complaining. The node_module folder contains an express folder as expected.

Also, my "process" is yielding the delightful: "Cannot find name 'process'.", as is my "__dirname".

All of this makes me feel that nodejs is not configured properly.

Can anyone help with these issues? I would look for an answer elsewhere, but I don't know where to look nor what for!

Comment: Do you have the type definitions installed?

Comment: Type definitions for nodejs? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Was missing:

```
/// <reference path="typings/express/express.d.ts" />
```

Easy.

Comment: If it's helpful, you can now include that file in the `tsconfig.json if it's easier.

Answer (score -2):

You may not have shown all your code, but I can't see anywhere:

```
var express = require('express')
```

Comment: `import * as express from 'express';` I see it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with TypeScript and was unaware of this convention. I've looked it up now. I'm just starting learning nodejs myself so suggested the way my tutorial states.

Comment: Not a problem. You should know; however, that this isn't TypeScript syntax. This is new JavaScript syntax. Specifically this is ES2015 module syntax.